# How would you implement sections with open MP with reduction

Tags: c, openmp

I was messing around with openMP. There was this question that asked to apply section to display the calculation result of each variable: totalsection1, totalsection2, and totalsection3. Each section is supposed to display each total value.I've tried implementing the sections before the  `pragma omp for reduction` and within but both give me syntax errors.

```
#include<omp.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 4000
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int ID = 0;
    int section1[ARRAYSIZE], section2[ARRAYSIZE], section3[ARRAYSIZE];
    int i, totalsection1 = 0, totalsection2 = 0, totalsection3 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        section1[i] = (i + 1) * 10;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        section2[i] = (i + 1) + 10;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
        section3[i] = (i + 1) * 2;
    }

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(3)
    { //start of parallel region 

#pragma omp for reduction (+:totalsection1)
        for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
#pragma omp critical
            totalsection1 = totalsection1 + section1[i];
        }
#pragma omp for reduction (+:totalsection2)
        for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
#pragma omp critical
            totalsection2 = totalsection2 + section2[i];
        }
#pragma omp for reduction (+:totalsection3)
        for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {
#pragma omp critical
            totalsection3 = totalsection3 + section3[i];
        }

#pragma omp sections 
        {
#pragma omp section 
            {
                printf("Hello from section 1\n");
                printf("The total value for section 1 is : %d", totalsection1);
                printf("\n");
            }

#pragma omp section 
            {
                printf("Hello from section 2\n");
                printf("The total value for section 2 is : %d", totalsection2);
                printf("\n");
            }

#pragma omp section 
            {
                printf("Hello from section 3\n");
                printf("The total value for section 3 is : %d", totalsection3);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }


    } //end of parallel region 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Why do you talk about sections but not use `omp parallel sections reduction(whatever)`? 2. If you reduct on a variable you don't need the critical section. 3. Critical sections are a bad idea, and *if* you needed them in your case, you could have used `atomic` which is more efficient.

Comment: Could you show me how that would look like?

Comment: `#pragma omp section` defines work for a single thread, `#pragma omp for` is a worksharing construct (defines work for a pool of threads). You cannot use a worksharing construct inside a section. For me it is not clear why you would like to do that (or what your real goal is).

Comment: OpenMP is typically used to maximize performance, to do so put the 3 loops inside one loop. `#pragma omp for reduction (+:totalsection1, totalsection2, totalsection3) \n 
for (i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) { totalsection1 +=  section1[i]; totalsection2 += section2[i]; totalsection3 += section3[i]; }`

Comment: @Laci Good point that a section gets only on thread. Invoke nested parallelism?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I do not know what the OP's aim is. One possible solution is to start 3 different tasks and use a taskloop construct inside each of the tasks.